# Users and permissions on a Raspi which is both a home and an owncloud server

Tags: security, webserver, nfs, home-server, owncloud

I'm a long time Linux desktop user but a total newbie in servers and security. Now I want to set up a Raspi (running Raspbian) to act as a CUPS print server, an NFS file server and backup storage, an Owncloud server and maybe even a small web or mail server in the long run.

Since I have no experience with servers, I'm a bit unsure if it is a good idea to have private backup data on the same machine that is accessible from the internet for e.g. Owncloud usage. Is there something that can or needs to be done to protect this data?

Currently I'm at the very beginning, just set up Raspbian, CUPS and set up the printer in the local network. Everything through the standard user "pi" preconfigured in Raspbian. How should I proceed when configuring NFS and Owncloud?

Thanks for any help,
Photon.

Comment: While SU may well be the best place to get this question answered, it strikes me that the folks on the Raspberry Pi (http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/) and Unix/Linux (http://unix.stackexchange.com/) SE sites might be more familiar.

Comment: A single Raspberry seems too weak (in terms of RAM) for all of these services at once. Also, if you're not experienced in security, I recommend you *don't* forward any ports nor open it to the whole internet until you're comfortable with securing and managing a Linux server.

Answer (score 1):

> How should I proceed when configuring NFS and Owncloud?

Owncloud is a PHP application which requires MySQL and Apache.  So by virtue of having Owncloud installed and running, you will be running the Apache web server already.

Apache can be configured to run as a single local user, typically `www-data`.  Every file Apache (and therefore any user that hits your webserver from the outside) can touch and potentially serve has to be accessible by the `www-data` user or `www-data` group.

PHP is a module that is called by Apache when a user hits a PHP script.  PHP will run as the same user as Apache is running.  However, PHP can attempt to access any file on your system.  It will not be successful if the permissions block it - i.e. unless the file is accessible by the `www-data` user or group (assuming defaults).

A PHP application, if it is not well written, might be vulnerable to exploits that let users browse any file PHP can access.  An example of something a hacker might try to do is send a malformed query to a PHP script and make it return `/etc/passwd` or possibly the contents of other world-readable configuration files in `/etc`.  Now this isn't terribly damaging to your system at that point in time, but could give an attacker information on valid accounts, which could help them if they are trying to crack a local account somehow.

OwnCloud has been around a while so it's relatively mature and tested in the field, but one point to take away from this: keep up on updates.

Apache itself can restrict files from being served with `.htaccess` files, but this is something Apache enforces, not Linux.  `.htaccess` files do not control what a PHP script can look at, just what files can be served via direct HTTP requests from a browser.

So:

- Keep up with the OS updates.
- Really you should run Owncloud on a separate physical (or virtual) system (another pi).  However, if you are just experimenting or testing, or careful with who you share your Owncloud IP, it should be relatively OK.
- Keep an eye on your webserver's logs (`/var/log/apache2` on Debian).  You may look into `goaccess` that can give you some easy to understand reports.
- Data you store with Owncloud, and on this system as a whole, should be backed up regularly and a copy kept off that system.
- Files you want in no way to be seen by Owncloud or the webserver should have permissions that deny access to the `www-data` group and users.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! I was following this guide: http://tech-blog.clericare.com/2013/08/how-to-deploy-owncloud-with-postgresql.html That is, using nginx and postgresql and putting Owncloud into a "jail", i.e. changing root to /var/lib/owncloud/ for the Owncloud PHP process as described in the guide. An external hard drive is mounted to /media/data/ and its subfolder /media/data/owncloud is mounted (with the "bind" option) to /var/lib/owncloud/data). Backups should be placed in /media/data/backups. Does this setup make sense or are there some potential security flaws? Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I have set up Owncloud in a "jail" using this howto: http://tech-blog.clericare.com/2013/08/how-to-deploy-owncloud-with-postgresql.html